# After Publisihing Worker Service as Windows Service it keeps failing with the error: System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, .net-core, windows-services, background-task

The worker service is a .net core 3.1, it works when I run it on VS 2019 (both debug and release), but after deploying/publishing and installing it with `sc.exe`, it keeps failing with the error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`.

I have checked and the only point I feel is the cause, maybe from the DI (which shouldn't be, since it runs perfectly on VS 2019), also the `appsettings.json` and `appsettings.Development.json` are included in the published file (so I see no reason why `IOptionsMonitor` or `IServiceScopeFactory` should be failing )

Comment: Why don't you attach Visual Studio debugger and track it down?

Comment: Thanks, by default windows service reads files from a `TEMP` directory after installing, hence the need to configure the `IHostBuilder` ro read from a specific directory where the appsettings are located with the executable file.  [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#use-contentrootpath-or-contentrootfileprovider]

Comment: Does that somehow stop you attaching a debugger??

Comment: Not at all, attaching the debugger was successful and it kept running without error nor stopping at the break-point I set (though I still need to learn how to use this method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, after installing a worker service as windows service, it copies the files needed to run to a `TEMP` folder, if you install with `sc` using defaults (`LocalSystem`), that has a folder pattern `C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\.net\<executable-name>\<random-hash>\`.

Whereas the `appsetings.json` or any settings files will not be copied there (see [microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#use-contentrootpath-or-contentrootfileprovider)).

Hence the need to direct the `IHostBuilder` or `IConfigurationBuilder` to where the settings files are located (more likely to where the executable was published).

I solved it with the following code (by setting the base path of the `IConfigurationBuilder`):

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
{            
    return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseWindowsService()
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, config) => {
            
            // Ensure that the appsettings.json files are in same folder with the executable   
            string pathToExe = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;
            string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(pathToExe);
            config.SetBasePath(dir);

        })
        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
        });
}
```

For futher reference see the following GitHub issues [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/32735) and [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/36356)